# Newly added column is not visible inside insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Added a new column to the existing table.
Column is also visible after firing select query.

But while inserting record into that table.
The new added column is not visible in

```
INSERT INTO template(ID,name,validity,status) 
VALUES (1,'sudhakar','2014-04-05',available)
```

In the above query **Status** is the newly added column which is not visible inside the insert query

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: It shows red color in column [status] while using it in insert query

Comment: try something like  `VALUES (1,'sudhakar','2014-04-05','available')` as value available is not valid input without single quotes.

Comment: @Justin....Restarted Management studio,it is now visible.

Comment: shouldn't this be 'available' ?

Answer (score 8):

If you change the structure of an object, you have to refresh IntelliSense

Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh local Cache

or

ctrl + shift + R